# Gpu crashed or d3d device removed

Tags: unreal-4, unreal, unreal-5

fellow StackExchange community.
Probably everyone who has worked with Unreal Engine 5 has had this error.
In general, it is associated with incorrectly configured video card drivers.
But as my own experience has shown, this is not the end of the matter.
Most of the projects I work on do not have files that require serious graphics processing (complete or almost no shaders, detailed textures, and so on).
I want to ask more experienced professionals, are there any possible ideas to solve this problem?
In advance, sincerely grateful for your suggestions.

For the test run, I used the default first-person shooter game.

### Error and logs

#### Errors at Crash text file

```
[2023.03.24-15.39.41:398][166]LogD3D12RHI: Error: PageFault: Found 0 active heaps containing page fault address
[2023.03.24-15.39.41:398][166]LogD3D12RHI: Error: PageFault: Found 0 released resources containing the page fault address during last 100 frames
[2023.03.24-15.39.41:398][166]LogD3D12RHI: Error: [GPUBreadCrumb] Last tracked GPU operations:
[2023.03.24-15.39.41:398][166]LogD3D12RHI: Error: [GPUBreadCrumb]   3D Queue 0 - Begin: Frame 12164 - Scene - Lights - DirectLighting - UnbatchedLights - First_Level.Sunlight - ShadowProjectionOnOpaque - VirtualShadowMapProjection(RayCount:8(Adaptive),SamplesPerRay:4,Input:GBuffer)
[2023.03.24-15.39.41:402][167]LogD3D12RHI: Error: [GPUBreadCrumb]   Copy Queue 0 - No Data
[2023.03.24-15.39.41:445][167]LogD3D12RHI: Error: [GPUBreadCrumb]   Compute Queue 0 - No Data
[2023.03.24-15.39.41:475][167]LogD3D12RHI: Error: DRED: No breadcrumb head found.
[2023.03.24-15.39.41:476][167]LogD3D12RHI: Error: DRED: No PageFault data.
[2023.03.24-15.39.41:476][167]LogD3D12RHI: Error: Memory Info from frame ID 12601:
[2023.03.24-15.39.41:476][167]LogD3D12RHI: Error:   Budget: 7288.00 MB
[2023.03.24-15.39.41:476][167]LogD3D12RHI: Error:   Used:   2007.76 MB
[2023.03.24-15.39.45:481][167]LogD3D12RHI: Error: PresentInternal(SyncInterval) failed 
 at D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\D3D12RHI\Private\D3D12Viewport.cpp:639 
 with error DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_REMOVED

[2023.03.24-15.39.45:517][167]LogWindows: Error: Error reentered: Fatal error: [File:D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\D3D12RHI\Private\D3D12Util.cpp] [Line: 868] 
CurrentQueue.Device->GetDevice()->GetDeviceRemovedReason() failed 
 at D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\D3D12RHI\Private\D3D1
```

#### Last Fatal Error in Logs

```
[2023.03.24-15.39.45:517][167]LogWindows: Error: Error reentered: Fatal error: [File:D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\D3D12RHI\Private\D3D12Util.cpp] [Line: 868] 
CurrentQueue.Device->GetDevice()->GetDeviceRemovedReason() failed 
 at D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\D3D12RHI\Private\D3D12Submission.cpp:910 
 with error DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_REMOVED
```

#### Unreal Engine 5 Error Image

[image]

#### Unreal Engine Process Error

[image]

### Computer components and software

Unreal Engine versions that I used: 4.27, 5.0, 5.1
Graphics card: Nvidia RTX 3050
RAM: Kingston KF2666C16D4/16G (4 items)
Processor: Intel12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-12500, 2995 MHz

### Solutions

The solutions I used:

```
1) Reinstalling drivers via GeForce Experience  
2) Reinstalling drivers manually in Safe Mode.  
3) Reinstalling drivers using Display Driver Uninstaller.  
4) Older drivers installation.  
5) Uninstalling conflicting software (ASUS CRATE ARMOURY).  
6) Entering the following commands into the console:  
dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /scanhealth  
dismount.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth  
dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup  
sfc /scannow  
chkdsk /f  
7) Checking your computer components for performance (including memory sticks).  
8) Using programs to adjust graphics card performance (like MSI Afterburner).  
9) Automatically installing Windows own drivers.  
10) Updating Windows.  
11) Set the power consumption in Nvidia Control Panel to the maximum performance.  
12) Reinstalling Unreal Engine.  
13) Hard reset of the system disc. I tried to reinstall the system.  
14) Disabling Intel UHD Graphics integrated graphics drivers.  
15) Disabling MSI Afterburner.  
16) Changing display settings in Unreal Engine.r.ScreenPercentage.  
17) Changing Unreal Engine graphics settings ( Cinematic, Ultra, High, etc.)  
18) Enabling Virtual Texting.  
19) Changing Directx12 on Directx11 and vice versa.  
20) To change the values in TDRDelay and TDRDGIDelay in Registers Editor.  
21) Uninstalling the Rivatunner statistics server
22) Switching from studio to game drivers and vice versa.
23) Undercloaking GPU (postponed an error but hasn't solved it).
24) Overclocking GPU (system freeze).
```

Comment: Additionally, you refer to "this error" & "this problem" but you haven't clearly defined what that is to the reader. If you're getting an error, include the exact error message (preferably as text) in your question. If no error is displayed visually, check the logs.

Comment: Can you walk us through the steps to create a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example of this problem? Try making a copy of your project and deleting stuff/reverting to defaults until the problem goes away, keeping only the minimum amount of custom code/assets/settings needed to trigger the error. Or start from a new project, and add as little as possible to cause the error, then tell js exactly what we need to do to see the same outcome. Once we can reproduce the error, we can test proposed solutions to be sure they'll work for your case.

Comment: Unfortunately, we did not solve it entirely, but I found out why it occurred. First, the problem was switching to a different monitor, especially when switching from one screen where the engine is located to another where a browser is. The monitor was not new, and a VGA to Display Port converter was used to connect it to the video card. Subsequently, the monitor was replaced with a new one, and the cable was upgraded from digital HDMI to HDMI.

Comment: The main problem, given the factors described above, was a sharp change in the image digitization rate.
A game engine was running on one monitor and a browser on the other. When switching from the first screen, the video frequency drops sharply, and when switching back to the first monitor, the video card does not have time to overclock.
I would be grateful if someone familiar with software applications like MSI Afterburner could tell me how to adjust the frequency correctly for stable operation.